# Does the series converge or diverge? (Ratio Test)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to figure out this series to not avail:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$$

[image showing my work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjpdU.jpg)

As you can see I am using the Ratio test which is suggested to be used with factorials however it seems like what I am ending up with should be $1$ over infinity which would be $0$. But this series is supposed to diverge? Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: $(2n)!\ne 2 n!$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdot\ldots\cdot2n}{n!}\ge \frac{n^n}{n!}$$

But applying the ratio test to this last series:

$$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\cdot\frac{n!}{n^n}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e>1$$

and thus the rightmost series above diverges and so does ours.

Answer (score 1):

The first choice for me here would be the $n^{th}$ term test because
$$\frac{(2n)!}{\left(n!\right)^2}={2n\choose n}$$
is a binomial coefficient, hence a positive integer, so
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{\left(n!\right)^2}\ne 0$$
The ratio test works as well, and you were OK up to
$$\begin{align}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} & =\frac{(2n+2)!}{\left((n+1)!\right)^2}\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{(2n)!}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!}{(n+1)^2\left(n!\right)^2}\frac{\left(n!\right)^2}{(2n)!}\\
 & =\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{4\left(1+\frac1{2n}\right)}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)}\end{align}$$
And I think you can determine the limit from this point in the calculation.

Comment: +1, nice observation regarding the binomial coefficient - I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2} = \frac{(n+1) * (n+2) * (n+3) * ... * (2n-1) * 2n}{n!}$

For example:

$\frac{(6)!}{(3!)^2} = \frac{1*2*3*4*5*6}{1*2*3*1*2*3} = \frac{4*5*6}{1*2*3} = 20$

$\frac{(10)!}{(5!)^2} = \frac{1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10}{1*2*3*4*5*1*2*3*4*5} = \frac{6*7*8*9*10}{1*2*3*4*5} = 252$

These terms get *larger,* not smaller, and cannot converge to anything.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{HINT}$

Use these facts:

\begin{align}
(n!)^2 &= (n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) ...)^2 \\
((n+1)!)^2 &= ((n+1)\cdot n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) ...)^2 \\
(2n)! &= (2n) \cdot (2n-1) \cdot (2n -2) ... \\
(2n+2)! &= ((2n+2) \cdot (2n+1) \cdot (2n) \cdot (2n-1)) ... \\
\end{align}

Do you notice how you can get rid of terms?

$\mathbf{Hint \,\, 2}$

The squares won't be a problem; you can think distribute the squares with ease since it's just multiplication. Again, think about how things cancel in this case as well.

The mistake you are making is on your second line where you changed $(2n)!$ to $2n!$ and as you can see from the first hint, they can't possibly be the same.

Let me know if you would like me to expand further.

Comment: @Downvoter May I know how I can improve the answer? Thanks!